# Extract sentence from HTML using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have extracted a component of interest from a HTML file using python([BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/))
My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from lxml import html
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


HTMLFile = open("/home/kospsych/Desktop/projects/dark_web/file", "r")

index = HTMLFile.read()
S = BeautifulSoup(index, 'lxml')

Tag = S.select_one('.inner')


print(Tag)
```

This prints the result of :

```
<div class="inner" id="msg_550811">Does anyone know if it takes a set length of time to be given verified vendor status by sending a signed PGP message to the admin (in stead of paying the vendor bond)?<br/><br/>I'm regularly on Agora but I want to join the Abraxas club as well.<br/><br/>Mindful-Shaman</div>
```

and of type:

```
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```

I would like somehow to remove the div tag and the br tags and just result with a string which will be the above sentence.
How could this be done efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.text` or `.get_text()` method:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(
    """<div class="inner" id="msg_550811">Does anyone know if it takes a set length of time to be given verified vendor status by sending a signed PGP message to the admin (in stead of paying the vendor bond)?<br/><br/>I'm regularly on Agora but I want to join the Abraxas club as well.<br/><br/>Mindful-Shaman</div>""",
    "html.parser",
)

Tag = soup.select_one(".inner")
print(Tag.get_text(strip=True, separator=" "))
```

Prints:

```
Does anyone know if it takes a set length of time to be given verified vendor status by sending a signed PGP message to the admin (in stead of paying the vendor bond)? I'm regularly on Agora but I want to join the Abraxas club as well. Mindful-Shaman
```